# What I Do to Full Join Use On Condition ">"?

Tags: sql

there are two tables ,I want to take data from one table that is larger than the other table, and display all data that is not larger than the other table

```
table A
| code | value |
| -- | -- |
| aa | 10|
| bb | 20|


table B
| code | value |
| -- | -- |
| aa | 30 |
| bb | 40 |
```

```sql
SELECT 
  COALESCE(a.code, b.code) AS code,
  a.value as va,
  b.value as vb
FROM A a
FULL JOIN B b 
ON a.code = b.code
AND a.value> b.value
```

the actual sql: operation_time and lock_time type is timestamp with time zone

```
 SELECT COALESCE(b.m_product_id, a.m_product_id) AS m_product_id,
            COALESCE(a.storage_location_id, b.storage_location_id) AS storage_location_id,
            a.qty,
            a.lock_time,
            b.operation_time,
            b.category,
            b.product_num
           FROM lock_storage_location_record a
             FULL JOIN out_in_storage_detail b ON a.storage_location_id = b.storage_location_id AND a.m_product_id = b.m_product_id AND b.operation_time > a.lock_time
          WHERE b.deleted = false and COALESCE(b.m_product_id, a.m_product_id) = 3309
```

result :

```
| code | va | vb |
| -- | -- | --|
| aa | 10 | null |
| bb | 20 | null |
```

expected :

```
| code | va   | vb   |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| aa   | 10   | null |
| bb   | 20   | null |
| aa   | null | 30   |
| bb   | null | 40   |
```

Comment: What does `>` have to do with the expected answer?

Comment: @drum I reedited my question, I just want to get the value of table a greater than the value of table b.If none of them match, you still need them to return something that doesn't match

Comment: Your explanation does not make sense. How is the result not correct?

Comment: @drum Table A does not match the content shown, but table B does not match the content not shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the expected result with same `Full Outer Join` sql

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(a.code, b.code) AS code,
  a.value as va,
  b.value as vb
FROM A a
FULL OUTER JOIN B b ON a.code = b.code AND a.value> b.value
```

#### Result :

> ```
> code |   va |   vb
> :--- | ---: | ---:
> aa   |   10 | null
> bb   |   20 | null
> aa   | null |   30
> bb   | null |   40
> ```

[SQL Server 2012 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f77ac821001bce1ab08402799fbbcc47)

Comment: FULL JOIN is FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: I simplified the problem before, please help me to see the actual SQL executed, this result is the same as the problem I described